# Using sed with regex to find and replace a string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, vim, sed

So I have the following string in my `config.fish`, and `init.vim`:

Fish: `eval sh ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-monokai.dark.sh`
Vim: `colorscheme base16-monokai`
Vim: `let g:airline_theme='base16_monokai'`

And I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

theme=$1
background=$2

if [ -z '$theme' ]; then

    echo "Please provide a theme name."

else

    if [ -z '$background' ]; then
        $background = 'dark'
    fi

    base16-builder -s $theme -t vim -b $background > ~/.config/nvim/colors/base16-$theme.vim &&
    base16-builder -s $theme -t shell -b $background > ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-$theme.$background.sh &&
    base16-builder -s $theme -t vim-airline -b $background > ~/.vim/plugged/vim-airline-themes/autoload/airline/themes/base16_$theme.vim

    sed -i -e 's/foo/eval sh ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-$theme.$background.sh/g' ~/Developer/dotfiles/config.fish
    sed -i -e 's/foo/colorscheme base16-$theme/g' ~/Developer/dotfiles/init.vim
    sed -i -e 's/foo/let g:airline_theme='base16_$theme'/g' ~/Developer/dotfiles/init.vim


fi
```

Basically the idea is the script will generate whichever theme is passed through using this [builder](https://github.com/base16-builder/base16-builder).

I have tried referring this [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) but I am not very skilled at regex so if anybody could give me a hand I would appreciate it.

What I need to happen is once the script is generated `sed` will look for the above strings and replace theme with the newly generated theme ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed -i "s|\(eval sh ~/\.config/fish/colors/base16-\)\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*\)\\(.*\)|\1$theme.$background\4|
" ~/Developer/dotfiles/config.fish
sed -i "s/\(base16\)\([-_]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\1\2$theme/g" ~/Developer/dotfiles/init.vim
```

Assuming in the second sed command that the theme is an alphanumeric string. If not, you can complete  the character range : `[a-zA-Z]` with additional characters (eg `[a-zA-Z0-9]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace something in sed using this syntax: `sed "s#regex#replacement#g"`. Because you have `/`s and `'`s in your strings, it's easiest not to need to escape them.

There are some characters that need to be escaped to make the regexes. `.` and `$` need to be escaped with a `\`. The `$` in the replacement string needs to be escaped too.

If you want to capture a certain part from match, it's easiest to use char classes. For example, `eval sh ~/\.config/fish/colors/base16-([^.]+)\.dark\.sh` would be the regex to use if you want your replacement to be `airline_theme='$1_base16_\$theme'`. In that case, the $1 in the replacement is the thing captured in the regex.

- `[^.]+`  will capture everything up to the next `.`

I hope this helps you to better understand regexes! This should be detailed enough to show you how to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes for parameter expansion not single quotes.
You need to escape the single quotes: `'hello'\''world'`

I will make one line for you and leave it as an exercise to fix the other lines

```
sed -i -e 's~\(let g:airline_theme='\''\)[^'\'']*\('\'\)'~base16_'"$theme"~' ~/Developer/dotfiles/init.vim
```

Comment: Hey Thanks @andlrc, I appreciate that but the problem was more with the regex I need to figure out how to find the previous `eval sh ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-monokai.dark.sh` without knowing the theme (monokai) i.e `eval sh ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-{*}.{*}.sh` but couldn't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The first character after the `s` in the sed expression string is used as the pattern separator, so by putting `/` first you have specified / as the separator.

Additionally using the single quote tells the shell not to expand any variables, you are going to want to use double quotes instead.

try something like

```
sed -i -e "s#foo#eval sh ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-$theme.$background.sh#g" ~/Developer/dotfiles/config.fish
```

as you've now commented that you needed to find the previous theme string instead of `foo`

```
sed -i -e "s#eval sh \~/\.config/fish/colors/base16-.*?\..*?\.sh#eval sh ~/.config/fish/colors/base16-$theme.$background.sh#g" ~/Developer/dotfiles/config.fish
```